dictionaries-common not installed error while Installing Ubuntu 22.04 Dual boot
New to Ubuntu and my first time installing Ubuntu 22.04 with Windows dual boot.
Somehow installed the server with desktop GUI, and have 2 errors preventing me from installing it further.

when booted with Ubuntu option from the boot menu in the command prompt the line display:

rtw_8821ce 0000:04:00.0: failed to send h2c command

This line comes nonstop but I was able to start and connect to the internet and put this question as well.
When I opt to configure the safe mode during installation and do network planning this above line is not displayed till I reboot under normal mode.

for any installation  including dictionaries-common

getting the same error:
sudo apt-get install /var/cache/apt/archives/dictionaries-common_1.28.14_all.deb

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aspell : Depends: dictionaries-common but it is not installed
 aspell-en : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 0.49.2) but it is not installed
 hunspell-en-us : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


I tried apt --fix-broken install the result is


sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dictionaries-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dictionaries-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
40 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/185 kB of archives.
After this operation, 783 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 198739 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dictionaries-common_1.28.14_all.deb ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/dict/words to /usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictiona
ries-common by dictionaries-common'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/share/dict/words.pre-dicti
onaries-common' with
  different file '/usr/share/dict/words', not allowed
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dictionaries-common_1.28.
14_all.deb (--unpack):
 new dictionaries-common package pre-installation script subprocess returned err
or exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dictionaries-common_1.28.14_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


